# Form input live calculation based on other input valiue

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on live currency calculator script, goal is to make live calculations based on form inputs.

so far thanks to your comments i achieved bellow:

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="usd">
<input type="text" id="gel">
<input type="text" id="eur">
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$("#gel").keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(isNaN(val)) { val =val.replace(/\D/g,''); }
  $('#usd').val(val / <?php echo $usd; ?>);
  $("#gel").val(val);
  $("#eur").val(val / <?php echo $eur; ?>);
});
$("#usd").keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(isNaN(val)) { val =val.replace(/\D/g,''); }
  $('#usd').val(val);
  $("#gel").val(val*<?php echo $usd; ?>);
  $("#eur").val(val*<?php echo $usd; ?>/<?php echo $eur; ?>);
});
$("#eur").keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(isNaN(val)) { val =val.replace(/\D/g,''); }
  $('#usd').val(val*<?php echo $eur; ?>/<?php echo $usd; ?>);
  $("#gel").val(val*<?php echo $eur; ?>);
  $("#eur").val(val);
});
</script>
```

Is it correct way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="usd">
<input type="text" id="gel">
<input type="text" id="inr">
```

//Jquery

```
$("#usd").keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = val.replace(/\D/g,'');
  $('#usd').val(val);
  $("#gel").val(val*55);
  $("#inr").val(val*10);
});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer rather than just supplying code.

Comment: Thanks for the code however in this case all the calculations are done via #USD input. my goal is to make calculation from any input form. for better image kindly check php in my first post. thank you again

Comment: is this correct way of doing it ?$("#gel").keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(isNaN(val)) { val =val.replace(/\D/g,''); }
  $('#usd').val(val*2);
  $("#gel").val(val);
  $("#eur").val(val*3);
});
$("#usd").keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(isNaN(val)) { val =val.replace(/\D/g,''); }
  $('#usd').val(val);
  $("#gel").val(val*2);
  $("#eur").val(val*3);
});
$("#eur").keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(isNaN(val)) { val =val.replace(/\D/g,''); }
  $('#usd').val(val*2);
  $("#gel").val(val*3);
  $("#eur").val(val);
});

Comment: Yes, put currency calculation all conditions inside 3 textbox keyup events.

Comment: you are amazing, how do i round up final value ? i have 15.298499999999999 i need 15.2985

Comment: var a = parseFloat(15.298499999999999).toFixed(4);
console.log(a);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery script as follow

```js
$("#usd").change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#gel").val(val*55);
  $("#inr").val(val*10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="usd">
<input type="text" id="gel">
<input type="text" id="inr">
```